# Problems with strncpy and how to fix it

Tags: c

I am learning C and reading through Learn C The Hard Way (ISBN-10: 0-321-88492-2). I am stuck on the exercise 17 'How to break it'.

Here is the problem from the book:

> There is a bug in this program because of strncpy being poorly
>   designed. Go read about strncpy then try to find out what happens when
>   the name or address you give is greater than 512 bytes. Fix this by
>   simply forcing the last character to '\0' so that it's always set no
>   matter what (which is what strncpy should do).

I have done some reading on strncpy and I understand that it is insecure because it doesn't add a null byte to the end of the string. However, I don't know how to pass in a large number of bytes to the function and I am not sure how to fix the null byte problem.

Below is the function which is using strncpy, `MAX_DATA` is set to 512.

```
void Database_set(struct Connection *conn, int id, const char *name, const char *email)
{
    struct Address *addr = &conn->db->rows[id];
    if(addr->set) die("Already set, delete it first");

    addr->set = 1;
    // WARNING: bug, read the "How To Break It" and fix this
    char *res = strncpy(addr->name, name, MAX_DATA);
    // demonstrate the strncpy bug
    if(!res) die("Name copy failed");

    res = strncpy(addr->email, email, MAX_DATA);
    if(!res) die("Email copy failed");
}
```

**How to Break it - EDIT**

Below is an example of how to break strncpy:

```
void Database_set(struct Connection *conn, int id, const char *name, const char *email)
{
    struct Address *addr = &conn->db->rows[id];
    if(addr->set) die("Already set, delete it first");

    addr->set = 1;
    // WARNING: bug, read the "How To Break It" and fix this

    char name2[] = {
      'a', 's', 't',
      'r', 'i', 'n', 'g'
    };
    char *res = strncpy(addr->name, name2, MAX_DATA);
    // demonstrate the strncpy bug
    if(!res) die("Name copy failed");

    res = strncpy(addr->email, email, MAX_DATA);
    if(!res) die("Email copy failed");
}
```

To fix, add a null byte to the end of the string. change `name2` to be:

```
  char name2[] = {
    'a', 's', 't',
    'r', 'i', 'n', 'g', '\0'
  };
```

or, add the following line above the strncpy function call

```
names2[sizeof(names2)-1] = '\0';
```

Comment: Passing in a large number of bytes is just the same as passing in a small number of bytes, only larger :)

Comment: I've written about `strncpy()` [here](http://the-flat-trantor-society.blogspot.com/2012/03/no-strncpy-is-not-safer-strcpy.html).

Comment: I would request my money back. In function `Database_set`: `char *res = strncpy(...); // demonstrate the strncpy bug if(!res) die("Name copy failed");`. `strncpy` never returns NULL, it always returns the destination pointer.

Comment: I've included the function that I am working on. @NigelHarper so I can just pass in a really long string and it will be larger than 512 bytes? sorry I am very next to C!

Comment: @KeithThompson thanks, great post. It makes more sense now

Comment: Exactly.  Each character in your string takes up a single byte, so you need a string that is more than 512 characters long.

Answer (score 4):

Another way to fix the `strncpy` *bug*, would be to fix the [`printf`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/printf) call

```c
void Address_print(struct Address *addr)
{
    printf("%d %.*s %.*s\n",
            addr->id, sizeof(addr->name), addr->name, sizeof(addr->email), addr->email);
}
```

This restricts printf to output at most the whole character array, but not more.

Answer (score 3):

Why not just replace strncpy with strlcpy?
According to the strlcpy man page :

```
 EXAMPLES
 The following sets chararray to ``abc\0\0\0'':

       (void)strncpy(chararray, "abc", 6);

 The following sets chararray to ``abcdef'' and does not NUL terminate
 chararray because the length of the source string is greater than or
 equal to the length parameter.  strncpy() only NUL terminates the
 destination string when the length of the source string is less than the
 length parameter.

       (void)strncpy(chararray, "abcdefgh", 6);

 Note that strlcpy(3) is a better choice for this kind of operation.  The
 equivalent using strlcpy(3) is simply:

       (void)strlcpy(buf, input, sizeof(buf));


 The following copies as many characters from input to buf as will fit and
 NUL terminates the result.  Because strncpy() does not guarantee to NUL
 terminate the string itself, it must be done by hand.

       char buf[BUFSIZ];

       (void)strncpy(buf, input, sizeof(buf) - 1);
       buf[sizeof(buf) - 1] = '\0';
```

Answer (score 3):

The man page for strncpy actually gives example code on how to fix this bug:

```
strncpy(buf, str, n);
if (n > 0)
   buf[n - 1]= '\0';
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do the following, assuming that `str1` and `str2` are character arrays:

```
strncpy(str1, str2, sizeof(str1) - 1);
str1[sizeof(str1)-1] = '\0';
```

This will always set the last character to `\0`, no matter how long `str2` is. But keep in mind that if `str2` is bigger than `str1`, then the string will be truncated.

Comment: @NigelHarper If you use `strlen(str1)`, you could never store a string larger than is currently in `str1`. `sizeof(str1) - 1` is the correct way in this case.

Comment: @NigelHarper No, he meant `sizeof`, assuming that the destination is an array (which is common). `strlen()` doesn't really make sense, especially if the destination is uninitialized at the beginning. Apart from that, I don't see what's wrong with this answer, it really doesn't deserve the downvote.

Comment: This is totally broken if str1 is not an array but a pointer. It's even worse broken if str1 is a pointer to fewer bytes than a char pointer. It's incredibly broken when trying to handle UTF-8 data, which nowadays the huge majority of strings will be, where it creates invalid strings.

Comment: @gnasher729; `This is totally broken if str1 is not an array but a pointer.`: I think you should read again answer's very first line: *assuming that str1 and str2 are character arrays*.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem there is that addr->name has not been initialized, so it is an empty pointer, it points no where.

So before you can use strncpy first you have to allocate memory to addr->name, otherwise it won't work.

And since it is a NULL pointer, NULL gets returned if you didn't set it up, then the if statement after will be true and the die function will stop the program.

You can look at the source code that the Database_create function does not initialize the two string pointers from the struct Address.