# Getting string with C function

Tags: c, string, function

I need to get strings dynamically but as I need to get more than one string, I need to use functions. So far I wrote this
(I put //**** at places i think might be wrong)

```
char* getstring(char *str);

int main() {

    char *str;
    strcpy(str,getstring(str));//*****
    printf("\nString: %s", str);
    return 0;
}

char* getstring(char str[]){//*****
    //this part is copy paste from my teacher lol
    char c;
    int i = 0, j = 1;
    str = (char*) malloc (sizeof(char));
    printf("Input String:\n ");
    while (c != '\n') {//as long as c is not "enter" copy to str
        c = getc(stdin);
        str = (char*)realloc(str, j * sizeof(char));
        str[i] = c;
        i++;
        j++;
    }
    str[i] = '\0';//null at the end
    printf("\nString: %s", str);
    return str;//******
}
```

`printf` in the function is working but not back in `main` function.
I tried returning `void`, getting rid of `*s` or adding, making another `str2` and tring to `strcpy` there or not using `strcpy` at all. Nothing seems to working. Am I misssing something? Or maybe this is not possible at all
//Thank you so much for your answers

Comment: We had to struggle in year 1 in here. The easy stuff in C is never easy for more than some 5% of people.

Comment: ask your  teacher to stop casting malloc

Comment: @coderredoc The casting is optional? I'd take itas self-discipline, if nothing else.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc

Comment: The memory is 1 too few for the `'\0'` terminator. Move `j++;` above the `realloc` line.

Comment: @coderredoc I see, thanks. I'll now criticize his teacher for using getc instead of fgetc (or unlike with gets there is a valid reason?)

Comment: @Weather j is always 1 more than i

Comment: Consider using [getline(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html) if it is available on your system.

Comment: @PaulStelian the first time `realloc` is called `j` is 1 so the memory allocation changes from 1 to 1. No room for terminator, as I said.

Comment: @Basile I think we all are taught to be portable, and getline definitely is not available on Windows.

Comment: @Weather OHH I see now

Comment: @PaulStelian indeed `i` is index, `j` is length (to include terminator).

Comment: On the 1st iteration `c` is used uninitialised.

Comment: @PaulStelian: but then we can always ask that same teacher to stop using `getline` :)

Answer (score 3):

Getting the string part can be taken from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41315322/use-scanf-to-read-lines-or-break-on-special-character/41315516#41315516). Only put a `\n` as input to the getline funtion.

```
char * p = getline('\n');
```

Three things :-
  don't cast malloc, check if `malloc/realloc` is  successful and `sizeof` is not a function.

Comment: `sizeof` may be not a function but does obey the syntax of a function! Just like C# typeof() builtin keyword

Comment: @PaulStelian.: yep

Answer (score 3):

The problem is not with the function that you are using, but with the way you try copying its result into an uninitialized pointer.

Good news is that you don't have to copy - your function already allocates a string in dynamic memory, so you can copy the pointer directly:

```
char *str = getstring(str);
```

This should fix the crash. A few points to consider to make your function better:

- `main` needs to `free(str)` when it is done in order to avoid memory leak
- Store `realloc` result in a temporary pointer, and do a `NULL` check to handle out-of-memory situations properly

Answer (score 3):

There are two things to take away from the lesson as it stands now:

(1) You should have one way of returning the reference to the new string, either as an argument passed by reference to the function OR as a return value; you should not be implementing both.

(2) Because the subroutine your teacher gave you allocates memory on the heap, it will be available to any part of your program and you do not have to allocate any memory yourself. You should study the difference between heap memory, global memory, and automatic (stack) memory so you understand the differences between them and know how to work with each type.

(3) Because the memory is already allocated on the heap there is no need to copy the string.

Given these facts, your code can be simplified to something like the following:

```
int main() {

    char *str = getstring();
    printf( "\nString: %s", str );
    return 0;
}

char* getstring(){
   .... etc
```

Going forward, you want to think about how you de-allocate memory in your programs. For example, in this code the string is never de-allocated. It is a good habit to think about your strategy for de-allocating any memory that you allocate.

Answer (score 1):

Let's simplify the code a bit:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char* getstring()
{
    char c = 0;
    int i = 0, j = 2;
    char *str = NULL;

    if ((str = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char))) == NULL)
        return NULL;

    printf("Input String: ");
    while (c = getc(stdin)) {
        if (c == '\n') break;

        str = (char*) realloc(str, j * sizeof(char));
        str[i++] = c;
        j++;
    }
    str[i] = '\0';
    printf("getstring() String: %s\n", str);
    return str;
}

int main()
{
    char *str = getstring();
    printf("main() String: %s\n", str);
    free(str);
    return 0;
}
```

Then execute:

```
$ make teststring && ./teststring 
cc     teststring.c   -o teststring
Input String: asdfasfasdf
getstring() String: asdfasfasdf
main() String: asdfasfasdf
```

Comment: You do not seem to have taken on the earlier comments about `j`.

Comment: ... and `while (c != '\n')` is undefined behaviour the first time - uninitialised .

Comment: The input character string contains a newline.